# Throwing C++ exceptions from linux system errors

Tags: c++, exception

I am looking for non-vulgar code that throws an exception when a UNIxs, and more specifically linux, system function returns an error.

Said code should skip throwing exceptions when there is no error. ( For example when errno is EAGAIN for a nonblocking read ). And preferably contain *FILE* and *LINE* of the line that the exception is thrown from.

I am very much uncertain whiat is going on with the new exception system and in particular the differences between system_catecories and generic_categories and where errno and strerror fit into it all.

Comment: Either code it by yourself, or consider using a framework like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out how it works by exploring the [Boost.System](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) library, which is where the relevant part of the C++ standard originated from.

To see how it may be used you can check out the [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library, which depends on Boost.System and is likely to become part of the standard in the future.